$n$ distinct integers have at least $\Omega(n^2)$ different subset sums?
Is there a real constant $c>0$, such that for all $A\subset\mathbb Z$, we have
$$\#\left\{\sum_{b\in B}b:B\subset A\right\}\ge c(\#A)^2. $$
Here $\# S:=|S|$ is the cardinal of a finite set $S$.
We can also ask a similar question. Is there a real constant $c>0$, for any finite cyclic group $G$ of prime order and for all $A\subset G$, the following inequality always holds:
$$\#\left\{\sum_{b\in B}b:B\subset A\right\}\ge \min\left(\#G,c(\#A)^2\right). $$
If this is true, then in particular when $\# A>\sqrt{\frac{\# G}c}$, sum of a subset of $A$ could take any value in $G$. For general finite abelian subgroup, the statement is false since we can take all elements of the form $(a,0)$ in $(\mathbb Z/N)\times(\mathbb Z/2)$. Also take a look at $\{2a:a\in\mathbb Z/N\}\subset\mathbb Z/2N$.
This Erdos style problem come from an easy observation that sum of a subset of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ ranges from $0$ to $1+2+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$. By induction on $n$, one can show that all integers between $0$ and $n(n+1)/2$ is possible. Of course one could take $\{-n,-n+1,\cdots,n\}$ to include negative integers. In this case there is still $n^2+n+1=\Omega(n^2)$ many possible subset sums. It seems that finding the exact lower bound of numbers of different subset sums is hard. So we only expect asymptotic forms.

Look into "Olson's constant", a variant of the Davenport constant (which is itself related to the Erdös–Ginzberg–Ziv theorem, although we're getting a little farther away from your particular question). As stated it only proves the "then in particular" part of your conjecture, but I bet the methods would generalize to the entire statement for prime cyclic groups (which then implies the statement for the integers).

What do you mean by "such that any $A$"?  Do you mean "such that there exists $A$", or "such that for all $A$"?  Please [edit] the question to make it clearer.  Please clarify the following question as well.  What does "always" mean?  Please ask only one question per post.  If you have two questions, you can post them separately, in two separate questions.

$n(n + 1)/2 + 1$ is also a lower bound on the number of distinct sums for any $A \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $a_1 < \ldots < a_n$. By induction, there are at least $n(n - 1)/2 + 1$ distinct subset sums in $\{a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1}\}$ $n$ of which are $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}a_i\\ \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}a_i\right) - a_1\\ \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}a_i\right) - a_2\\ \vdots \\ \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}a_i\right) - a_{n - 1}$$ Adding $a_n$ to the corresponding subsets gives $n$ extra distinct subset sums (the $n$ sums are different from each other and all greater than $\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}a_i$).
EDIT: For this to work, all $a_i$ must be positive. Otherwise, proceed as in the comment by @SeanEberhard

For the last paranthetical sentence you seem to be assuming $a_n > 0$. And indeed the lower bound $n(n-1)/2+1$ does not hold for $n=3$ and ${a_1,a_2,a_3} = {-1,0,1}$. But anyway it is OK to assume everything is positive because you can just split the set into its positive and negative parts and take the larger one, so you will still get a quadratic lower bound.

Also, here is a more explicit way of writing your proof, assuming everything is positive. Set $a_0 = 0$. Define $A_{i,j} = (a_1 + \cdots + a_j) - a_i$ for $0 \le i \le j \le n$. Then the observation is that $A_{i,j}$ are all distinct for $0 \le i < j \le n$. Indeed, $A_{0,j-1} = A_{j,j} < A_{j-1, j} < \cdots < A_{0, j}$ for all $j=1,\dots,n$.
